# Visual Studio 2017 Webpack Hot Module Replacement DotNetCore IIS AppPool Permissions [HMR]

Tags: angular, iis, webpack, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've been using VS 2017 Preview's Angular template to build out a SPA and ran in to a bit of a problem with **HMR**.

Firstly, [HMR] works like a champ in any web configuration *( project and IIS Express )* with the exception of IIS.  When running in IIS, VS tooling creates a Web.config with a wrapper class for attaching to the web process *( including just in case it's relevant )*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note that I added the **appSettings** bit as it results in the generated argfile container that env variable; not sure it's needed.

Anyway, here's what I get in the output console when launching the browser from VS:

[image: Warning from AspNet Core Server]

> WARNING: Webpack dev middleware is not enabled because the server
>   process does not have sufficient permissions. You should either remove
>   the UseWebpackDevMiddleware call from your code, or to make it work,
>   give your server process user account permission to write to your
>   application directory and to read all ancestor-level directories.

I fumbled my way thru some articles on how IIS injects the server process with an app pool identity and went ahead with updating the **permissions** adding  write and execute for the generated SID:

[image: IIS App Pool Permissions]

Unfortunately, this didn't have any effect.

Furthermore, I know the error states:

> and to read all ancestor-level directories.

however, outside of the IIS Manager app, I cannot grant access to the ancestor directories as that user is "special" and not in my local user directories.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can get the permissions worked out, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use IIS as a development web server? I am not sure doing HRM outside of a local dev web server is something you want to pursue, but I would like to hear some reasons for wanting to do this, other than seeking a new form of torture in the setup. :)

Comment: Is, I am a masochist, a good enough reason lol?  Firstly, I'd have to say, if it's not a typical workflow, why does the Visual Studio tooling support it as an option in the Debug section of the project properties?  Anyway, admittedly, .NET development is not my forte, so maybe I am being naive.  To answer your question, I have multiple interdependent  web services running.  Because of the service dependencies, I need these up and running all the time. It's easier to have IIS simply point to my project locations and host all of these sites directly without any setup from me.